# import error, ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/../../src/../any-ascii': fs.js (1800:7)

Tags: javascript, react-native, node-modules, npm-install

In my expo reactnative app I want a smart search functionality in search box, if the user searches “Ömıç“, the system should search for “Ömıç“, “Omic” and the other similars.

For this I import any-ascii library npm package, https://www.npmjs.com/package/any-ascii

However when I try to use it in the files it throws ;

`ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/../apps/mobile/src/Goal/any-ascii': fs.js (1800:7)`

I don't figure this out, any idea?

PS: Please DON'T ask :

- Does it exist ..
- Did you import ..
- Do you have the path or file

like that..

The answer is YES for all of them, just answer if you have any idea for the issue.
Thanks

Comment: any solution to this yet?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to

1. Clear watchman watches and associated triggers

   watchman watch-del-all
2. Clear metro cache

   rm -rf ${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/metro-*
3. restart project

   npm start -- --reset-cache

Comment: Thank you for your response Supriya, unfortunately same result, the error is still continue.

Answer (score 0):

try docker cp <file.txt> 2dfd3de6578:/root/user/mydir/ for each individual files or dirs. it worked in my case.

Comment: The question doesn't mention Docker so this doesn't seem like a good general solution.